# href link jquery ajax form won't send data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been playing around with this for hours now, can't figure it out.

I have a page ***signup.php*** with form that's handled by ajax. If I was to make this page the main page and fill out the form, it works well calling the url: ***register.php*** in the ajax script, but if I access this same ***signup.php*** page from my main ***index.php***  page through an href link it breaks the ajax. The form doesn't work. Why?

Here are my codes (truncated for relevancy)

***index.php*** This page contains the link to ***signup page***.

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>Carelincs</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <p>My main page content</p>

        <a href="../views/signup.php">Register</a>

        </div>
</div>
```

hre

signup page- page with form and ajax

***signup.php***

```
<body>
    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {

                var formData = $("#register").serializeArray();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../pages/register.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: onSuccess,

                });

                return false;
            });
        });


        function onSuccess(data, status) {

            data = $.trim(data);
            $("#message").text(data);
        }

        function onError(data, status) {
            data = $.trim(data);
            $("#message").text(data);
        }
    </script>
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                    <h1>Carelincs</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                <form action="" method="POST" id="register">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chekbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true" />
                    <label for="checkbox-mini-0">Remember me</label>
                    <br />  <a href="../views/forogotpswd">Forgot Password</a>

                    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
                </form> <a href="../views/signup.php">Register</a>

                <p id="message"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not cached in any way?

Comment: no, cache is set to false in the script. Where else would it be cached?

Comment: You do have jQuery imported within `signup.php`, right?

Comment: @Ninsly i tried setting the `$.ajaxSetup({ cache:false})` still nothing

Comment: @Gabor jQuery is imported and works fine. If I make the signup.php the index page and fill out the form it works. But when I access the form from another page through a link it doesn't.

Comment: When opening the developertools of your browser, and checking the console, do you see any javascript errors reported when trying to submit the form?

Comment: @Gabor no i don't see any error, but I noticed the POST is going to **signup.php** page instead of **register.php** that data is not leaving that page.

Comment: Note, Not certain if issue ; at `signup.php` appear link to same page `<a href="../views/signup.php">Register</a>` following `form` element ?

Comment: @guest271314 I am not sure I follow.

Comment: At `signup.php` there appear `<a>` element with `href` to same page ? Does that link get clicked ? perhaps affecting form submission ? Not view clearly why form not process correctly ; just indicating item where not certain why `<a>` element present with `href` to same page next to form ?

Comment: @guest271314 the first code is `index.php` file which has an href link to the `signup.php` file. And yes the link gets clicked and it brings the user to the `signup.php` file. I think it definitely does but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: At OP , see **signup.php** see `<a href="../views/signup.php">Register</a>` . Linking back to same page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research and playing around, I found the problem and solution thanks to @guest271314 for the hint.

The `<a href="../views/signup.php">Register</a>` was triggering the ajax and screwing up with the form, and all I had to do was change it to

```
<a href="../views/signup.php" rel="external">Register</a>
```

I added the `rel=external` and viola that disabled ajax for the link and my form works correctly.